# select rows with concate date time in where condition

Tags: php, mysql

Problem: select rows with concate date time where condition shows wrong result.

mysql:

```
select CONCAT(end_date,' ',logout_time) from login where status in (1,3) and 
staff_id='1' and travel_date<='2018-08-25' and end_date>='2018-08-25' and 
CONCAT(end_date,' ',logout_time)>='"2018-08-25 23:13"'
```

Result:

2018-08-25 03:59:00

what is the problem in this query?

Comment: ok, what's result you have and what did you except ?

Comment: my result should be higher then 2018-08-25 23:13

Comment: but  2018-08-25 03:59:00

Comment: Why are you comparing to `'"2018-08-25 23:13"'` ? Remove the `"` maybe? And maybe cast `CONCAT(end_date,' ',logout_time)` to a `date`, it's a string right now.

Comment: oh... thank you it works.